# How do i fix this error I'm getting this error below warning in my Xcode 13.0 on my ios flutter application

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm running into this error below in Xcode version 13.0

The iOS Simulator deployment
target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
is 9.0 to 15.0.99.

[This is the image showing the errors I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afqRr.png)

My deployment target is 15.0

[deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmcnm.png)

my pod file

[podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htsak.png)

Comment: You mus create e new one simulator by Xcode with iOS target >= 9 and <= 15 then selct it as target to debug or run your app.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. [ask]